# How to obtain time markers for video splitting using python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on my MSc project which is researching automated deletion of low value content in digital file stores. I'm specifically looking at the sort of long shots that often occur in natural history filming whereby a static camera is left rolling in order to capture the rare snow leopard or whatever. These shots may only have some 60s of useful content with perhaps several hours of worthless content either side.

As a first step I have a simple motion detection program from Adrian Rosebrock's tutorial [http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/#comment-393376]. Next I intend to use FFMPEG to split the video.

What I would like help with is how to get in and out points based on the first and last points that motion is detected in the video.

Here is the code should you wish to see it...

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import datetime
import imutils
import time
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", help="path to the video file")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type=int, default=500, help="minimum area size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# if the video argument is None, then we are reading from webcam
if args.get("video", None) is None:
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time.sleep(0.25)

# otherwise, we are reading from a video file
else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

# initialize the first frame in the video stream
firstFrame = None

# loop over the frames of the video
while True:
    # grab the current frame and initialize the occupied/unoccupied
    # text
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
    text = "Unoccupied"

    # if the frame could not be grabbed, then we have reached the end
    # of the video
    if not grabbed:
        break

    # resize the frame, convert it to grayscale, and blur it
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)

    # if the first frame is None, initialize it
    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gray
        continue

    # compute the absolute difference between the current frame and
    # first frame
    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # dilate the thresholded image to fill in holes, then find contours
    # on thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # if the contour is too small, ignore it
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < args["min_area"]:
            continue

        # compute the bounding box for the contour, draw it on the frame,
        # and update the text
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = "Occupied"

    # draw the text and timestamp on the frame
    cv2.putText(frame, "Room Status: {}".format(text), (10, 20),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p"),
        (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # show the frame and record if the user presses a key
    cv2.imshow("Security Feed", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
    cv2.imshow("Frame Delta", frameDelta)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key is pressed, break from the lop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```